# Excluding a site from another SP16 site search result

Tags: search-results

I wanted to exclude the content of a specific site from being shown in another site search result. I tried excluding the site by defining the query rule but it didn't work. I need to have the local search so I can't turn off the search.

If you have any ideas please let me know.